# Set up post page like JAMA articles

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I'm well aware that there are several plugins for creating custom post types.

I'm also well aware that what I'm asking probably requires alot of hard coding.

But nevertheless, have a look at this page: [JAMA Medicine Article](http://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamacardiology/fullarticle/2619238)

It is a super nice way of laying out a post which is an article with figures, references and links. And it is also responsive.

Is there any neat way of doing this without going to MIT?

Cheers

Comment: The referenced article does look great and recreating something similar is definitely possible in WordPress. As posted, the question is too broad though. To replicate the JAMA setup, you'd likely want to use custom post types (article content, references?), attachments (for images and supplemental information), custom taxonomies (online/offline, free/paid classification, categories), lots of meta data, and a membership implementation (roles/caps). This setup would also require plenty of JS for handling the tabbed layout, smooth scrolling table of contents, modals, sharing dropdowns, etc.